# All rotations about a point in the complex plane also Möbius maps

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Is my claim true? If so, is my "proof" correct?

Claim: All rotations about a point in the complex plane also Möbius maps.
Proof: We have shown that the set of Möbius maps is a group. So we can do the following scaling, translations, and inversions.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
f(z+k) & =\frac{az+(ak+b)}{cz+(ck+d)} \text{ where } a(ck+d)-c(ak+b)=ad-bc \neq 0 \\
f(kz) & = \frac{akz+b}{ckz+d} \text{ where } (ak)d-b(ck)=k(ad-bc) \neq 0 \text{ if } k \neq 0 \\
f(\frac{1}{z})=\frac{bz+a}{dz+c} \text{ where } bc-ad \neq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Hence Möbius transformations composed with these generators yield further Möbius transformations and the result follows.

Comment: How do rotations about an arbitrary point enter into your argument...?

Comment: That is where I am having trouble with

Comment: So you're confident your argument is _not_ correct? (Just trying to figure out what you believe to be true, and what have to work with.) Do you have any reason to expect your claim _is_ true? As a start it may help to write down the definition of a rotation, and to think about whether any of your generating transformations are rotations about some point.

Comment: I think it is right since you can write a f(z) and matrix in terms of rotations. I just can seem you prove it

Comment: You're right that a Möbius transformation can be written in terms of a real matrix, and a plane rotation can be written as a real matrix, but that's something of a coincidence for the purposes of your question. Do you have an instructor you can consult? It sounds like you may need extensive clarification on the background of your question before tackling the question itself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Normal_form may help, too.